# How to draw icon with image or text in center?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I have tried to draw icon in OpenLayers:

```
style: (feature: FeatureLike) => {
            return new Style({
              image: new Icon({
                color: "red",
                scale: 0.5,
                crossOrigin: "anonymous",
                src: `./assets/images/${icon}.png`,
              }),
              text: new Text({
                text: "1",
                fill: new Fill({
                  color: "#fff",
                }),
              }),
            });
          },
```

I want to use the same blank of icon but change only image inside and color icon.

How to do that properly in OpenLayers?

Answer (score 0):

One option created from the related question [Add a Text next to the point Open Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54907386/add-a-text-next-to-the-point-open-layer), modified to add customizable colors.

http://www.geocodezip.com/OL_6.14.1_multipleLabelledMarkersOption2colored.html

parses a string like: `['-117.3523286', '33.2171511', '#FF0000', 'KOKB']`
which is: `[lng, lat, color, text]` for each marker.

```
// modified from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54907386/add-a-text-next-to-the-point-open-layer
var iconFeatures=[];
coords.forEach((elem, ind, arr) => {
  coord = elem.split(',')
  var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([parseFloat(coord[0]), parseFloat(coord[1])], 'EPSG:4326',     
      'EPSG:3857')),
      name: coord[3],
      color: coord[2]
  });
  iconFeatures.push(iconFeature);
});

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: iconFeatures 
});

var labelStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    text: new ol.style.Text({
        font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
        overflow: true,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#000'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#fff',
            width: 3
        })
    })
});

vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: function(feature) {
      labelStyle.getText().setText(feature.get('name'));
      iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        image:  new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 20,
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#fff'
          }),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: feature.get('color')
          })
        })
  });
      return [new ol.style.Style({
        image:  new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 20,
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#fff'
          }),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: feature.get('color')
          })
        })
  }), labelStyle];
    }
});
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

[image: screenshot of example]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-117.1610838, 32.715738]),
    zoom: 10
  }),
});
// data for markers
var customMarker = [
    {lng:-117.1933038, lat: 32.7338006, icaocode: "KSAN", name: "San Diego International Airport", height: "5", callsign: "KSAN", color: "#FF0000"},
    {lng:-117.1414123, lat: 32.8127254, icaocode: "KMYF", name: "Montgomery Field", height: "130.1", callsign: "KMYF", color: "#00FF00"},
    {lng:-117.2792408, lat: 33.1268216, icaocode: "KCRQ", name: "McClellan-Palomar Airport", height: "101", callsign: "KCRQ", color: "#0000FF"},
    {lng:-116.9810485, lat: 32.5705504, icaocode: "KSDM", name: "Brown Field", height: "160", callsign: "KSDM", color: "#FFFF00"},
    {lng:-116.9725114, lat: 32.8267321, icaocode: "KSEE", name: "Gillespie Field", height: "118", callsign: "KSEE", color: "#00FFFF"},
    {lng:-116.9115525, lat: 33.0409315, icaocode: "KRNM", name: "Ramona Airport", height: "425", callsign: "KRNM", color: "#FF00FF"},
    {lng:-117.3523286, lat: 33.2171511, icaocode: "KOKB", name: "Oceanside Municipal Airport", height: "8.5", callsign: "KOKB", color: "#FF0000"},
];
var coords = [];
for (var i = 0; i < customMarker.length; i++) {
  coords.push(customMarker[i].lng + "," + customMarker[i].lat + "," + customMarker[i].color + "," + customMarker[i].icaocode);
  console.log("i=" + i + ":" + coords[i])
}

// from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54907386/add-a-text-next-to-the-point-open-layer
var iconFeatures = [];
coords.forEach((elem, ind, arr) => {
  coord = elem.split(',')
  console.log(coord);
  var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([parseFloat(coord[0]), parseFloat(coord[1])], 'EPSG:4326',
      'EPSG:3857')),
    name: coord[3],
    color: coord[2]
  });
  iconFeatures.push(iconFeature);
});

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: iconFeatures
});

var labelStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  text: new ol.style.Text({
    font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
    overflow: true,
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: '#000'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#fff',
      width: 3
    })
  })
});

vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: function(feature) {
    console.log("feature.name=" + feature.get('name') + " color=" + feature.get('color'));
    labelStyle.getText().setText(feature.get('name'));
    iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 20,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: '#fff'
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: feature.get('color')
        })
      })
    });
    return [new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 20,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: '#fff'
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: feature.get('color')
        })
      })
    }), labelStyle];
  }
});
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.14.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.14.1/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <title>OpenLayers example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```